# Improving database record retrieval throughput with appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

Using AppEngine with Python and the HRD retrieving records sequentially (via an indexed field which is an incrementing integer timestamp) we get 15,000 records returned in 30-45 seconds.  (Batching and limiting is used.)  I did experiment with doing queries on two instances in parallel but still achieved the same overall throughput.

Is there a way to improve this overall number without changing any code?  I'm hoping we can just pay some more and get better database throughput.  (You can pay more for bigger frontends but that didn't affect database throughput.)

We will be changing our code to store multiple underlying data items in one database record, but hopefully there is a short term workaround.

Edit: These are log records being downloaded to another system. We will fix it in the future and know how to do so, but I'd rather work on more important things first.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to retrieve such large number of entities at once? If you have such requirement then maybe there is a problem with your design rather than with HRD performance.

Comment: I will second what @illia-frenkel said above. Maybe consider designing your application to include using `memcache` and being cacheable? Since you're not providing any more info, I'd advise watching **App Engine Datastore Under the Covers** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM and **Building Scalable Web Apps with App Engine** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh9_t5W6MTE from Google IO 2008. Also read Jeff Dean's http://highscalability.com/numbers-everyone-should-know

Comment: I've added a clarifying edit.  I've seen other reports of similar performance.  Google let you pay for more front end performance so I was hoping they would let you pay for more database throughput too.

Comment: I seem to remember discussions in the past (on groups) that incrementing integer timestamp can have a negative performance on retrieval, becuase the underlying data is located on the same "tablet" which means the fetches loose some level of concurrency across different parts of the datastore,  (ok maybe I haven't described it properly. ;-)  Notice with the upcoming updates the id's of keys auto generated will be distributed.  From the release notes "The dev_appserver now allocates automatic ids using the 'scattered' id allocation policy by default.",

Comment: Mind you I am probably completely wrong ;-)

Comment: @TimHoffman thanks for the memories :-) Unfortunately there is only one field we index and it is the one we query/sort against: the incrementing integer timestamp.  The actual record ids are whatever Google automatically generates.  If something like using floating point instead of integer did the trick we'd jump on it.

Comment: @RogerBinns  did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the records on different entity groups. That might force them to go to different physical servers. Read entity groups in parallel from multiple threads or instances.
Using cache mght not work well for large tables.

Comment: Our plan is to stuff more of our records into each record that AppEngine sees which will help a lot.  Using different entity groups is similar amount of development work, and is something I'll consider when updating the code.  Sadly it isn't a short term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can cache your records, like use Memcache:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/

This could definitely speed up your application access. I don't think that App Engine Datastore is designed for speed but for **scalability**. Memcache however is.

BTW, if you are conscious about the performance that GAE gives as per what you pay, then maybe you can try setting up your own App Engine cloud with:

- [AppScale](http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/)
- [JBoss CapeDwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf)

Both have an active community support. I'm using CapeDwarf in my local environment it is still in BETA but it works.

Comment: Memcache won't help in this case due to the nature of data and queries.  I download the data to a local workstation and use MongoDB where I can retrieve 30k records per second and that includes a complex query and single threaded Python code that does contextual processing across them.  Eventually we plan to use AWS or something similar.   I'm still somewhat surprised that the datastore gives you 15k records per 30-45 seconds whether you pay Google $0 and have one low front end, or pay them hundreds and have several.

Comment: Ok I see, anyway, why not use a pure MongoDB solution, that might be faster. They say MongoDB is the fastest...

Comment: We know what to do in the medium to long term.  This question was purely what to do in the short term - I really was hoping that the answer involved paying Google a little more to get improved performance.

Answer (score -1):

Move to any of the in-memory databases. If you have Oracle Database, using [TimesTen](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/timesten/overview/) will improve the throughput multifold.

Comment: The question is about appengine's database at google.  It isn't oracle nor is timesten applicable.